# SD card questions

Tags: sd-card

So I recently bought a raspberry pi 2 model b. I am new to all of this so please forgive my lack of knowledge and youthful naivety.

It is recommended on the website that I purchase a 4gb sd card with NOOBS pre installed. However it also suggests that I can buy a regular sd card and install NOOBS myself (which I've opted to do).

I'm thinking of this. What do you guys think? Is it compatible with a raspberry pi 2?

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B0036V9AGU/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?qid=1443885953&sr=8-1&pi=SY200_QL40&keywords=raspberry+pi+2+sd+card&dpPl=1&dpID=41%2BZoQJ8byL&ref=plSrch

Comment: Get at least an 8GB card (so a 16GB card will be fine).  You will not get the recommended Raspbian to fit in 4GB.

Answer (score 3):

For complete compatibility information, check out http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards. There are 2 models of a Kingston 16GB microSDHC card listed, one that is reported to work, and one that seems to have issues. The one you link to in 16GB capacity is of type "SDC10" which is reported to NOT WORK. Same for the 8GB capacity. The 32GB version of the card you picked DOES seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

I just did what you're describing. I bought an 8gb sd card and installed noobs onto the card. IT's incredibly easy. Buy any sd card and use the raspberrypi.org website to download Noobs. Follow the instructions and pick whatever operating system you want.